# Horde configuration

Tags: apache-http-server, php, windows-server-2008-r2

I´m trying to configure Horde in a Windows Foundation 2008 R2 running Apache.

I followed the instructions here: [Installing Horde Framework 5](http://www.horde.org/apps/horde/docs/INSTALL#installing-with-pear)

I got stuck here:

> 3. Completing Configuration
>      You can now access Horde without a password, and you will be logged in as an administrator.

It is not clear how but I browsed: `http://myserver/horde` and got and error claiming the system is unactivated.

If I browse to:  `http://myserver/horde/test.php` then I get output about the version and obviously, no applications installed.

It seems strange however that my `horde/config/config.php` has it disabled:

```
$conf['testdisable'] = true;
```

(it doesn´t matter if I set it to `true` or `false`. It always runs)

How do I activate Horde? Do I need to edit some file? What did I miss during installation?

Comment: you can select the answer as accepted gaining points and providing a answered question for other users. Are the links to "http://myserver/horde and http://myserver/horde/test.php" down for a long time or there as display not as a link? If display

Comment: for display http-://myserver/horde ran out of time on the top comment added a ' - ' after http

Answer (score 0):

*it seems strange however that my horde/config/config.php has it disabled:*
The file copied has an incorrect name. It should be **config.php** (However it would be better to have a clearer message from Horde about missing config.php instead of an "unactivated" system)
After that:
http://myserver/horde
worked fine.